# Stocktwits Symbols filter flag throwing errors

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp, stocktwits

I'm currently trying to integrate the Stocktwits symbols multicall api into my website. Using ajax jsonp, I can indeed get it working and throw flags such as limit, but whenever I try to use the filter flag I receive a GET  500 error. What is strange is I can use said filter on the single symbol call api and it works fine. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Like I said before, I can already get the symbols multicall to work, so it's not authentication, it's just the filter flag. Below are my working examples followed by my code that is not working. I am currently running this on  localhost

Single call that works:

```
StocktwitsJsons = $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/AAPL.json?callback=?", 
        dataType: 'json',
      data:{ 
        limit:8,
        filter: 'top'
        },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data) {
       callback(data, tickerList, assetIds);
      }}
  });
```

Multi-call that works:

```
stocktwitsJsons = $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbols.json?callback=?", 
        dataType: 'json',
      data:{ access_token: token, 
        symbols: symbols, 
        limit:8
        },
      success: function(data) {
          if (data) {
          console.log(data);
         callback(data, tickerList, assetIds);
        }}
    });
```

Multi call that does NOT work:

```
StocktwitsJsons = $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbols.json?callback=?", 
        dataType: 'json',
      data:{ access_token: token, 
        symbols: symbols, 
        limit:8,
        filter:'top'
        },
      success: function(data) {
          if (data) {
          console.log(data);
         callback(data, tickerList, assetIds);
        }}
    });
```

Comment: Well it seems that you trigger a serverside error. So if you don't control the server, there is nothing you can do except to omit the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will correct the documentation this is an error. Currently we do not allow filtering on the multisymbol endpoint. It is on the roadmap to add. Sorry this is why it is not working for you.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Was very confused. Doubt this is the place to ask, but any chance of this being included in the near future? How I'm using it I get a constant stream of random folks saying 'yay AAPL/MSFT/GOOG' and the like which fills up most of my calls.

Comment: Speedysteve this is filter should now work like the others for multiple symbol endpoint.filter=top should work now.